# How to show the content in second response for ajax's authorization and cors?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cors

I have build basic authorization and cors in vps.

curl -X  OPTIONS -i  http://111.111.111.111

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 15 Sep 2018 08:07:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: httpd/unix-directory
```

curl -u xxxx:xxxx   -i  http://111.111.111.111/remote.php

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 15 Sep 2018 08:08:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
Last-Modified: Sat, 15 Sep 2018 07:54:13 GMT
ETag: "24-575e43f02c324"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 36


<?php
echo  '{"name","myname"}';
?>
```

You can see that authorization and cors are in good status.

The test-ajax-cors.html in my local directory `/var/www/html`.

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
function Ajax( ) {
    var url = 'http://111.111.111.111/remote.php';
    $.ajax(url, {
        type:"post",   
        crossDomain: "true",
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSend:function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',"Basic " + btoa("xxxx:xxxx"))},
        success:function(response){
        data = JSON.stringify(response);
            alert(data);
            mytext = $("#remote");
            mytext.append(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error");
        } 
    });
};
</script>

<input type="button" value="show content" onclick="Ajax();">
<p id="remote">the content on remote webpage</p>
```

The remote.php in `http://111.111.111.111`.

cat   /var/www/html/remote.php

```
<?php
echo  '{"name","myname"}';
?>
```

Type `127.0.0.1/test-ajax-cors.html` ,click `show content`,
1.i got alert info: error
2.remote.php was called for two times by `127.0.0.1/test-ajax-cors.html` (the `show content` button in `127.0.0.1/test-ajax-cors.html`  was clicked for just one time).

[image: the first response]
when to call remote.php for the first time, no content in remote.php's resposne.
The first request maybe a CORS-preflight request , browsers send an OPTIONS request without any Authorization header,and in my case the server send a 200 status code to browser,it means that everything is in good status.

[image]

The content in remote.php's response when to call remote.php for the second time.
How to make the content in second response to show by  `127.0.0.1/test-ajax-cors.html`.
Thank to Sally CJ's notice.

```
yum install mod_php
systemctl restart httpd
```

Type `127.0.0.1/test-ajax-cors.html` ,click `show content`.
1.alert error info

[image]

2.`remote.php` were called for two times,all the response for `remote.php` are same.

```
{"name","myname"}
```

[image]
[image]

The content is what i expect,why can't show it in webpage  `127.0.0.1\test-ajax-cors.html`,which result the alert error info?

Comment: Seems like the server is not "seeing"/treating/serving the file `remote.php` as a PHP file.. Try checking your Apache config and/or the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: yum install mod_php

Comment: systemctl restart httpd

Comment: Got {"name","myname"} as response,issue remains.

Comment: Change the `alert("error");` to `alert(e.responseText);` and see what it says.

Comment: Ajax every cors url,will lead one OPTIONS request and a normal request,OPTIONS request is sended by browser.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature You're expecting a JSON-encoded response (you set the `dataType` to `json` in the `jQuery.ajax()` call), and if you enter `JSON.parse('{"name", "myname"}')` in the console, you'd get an error; hence it's likely the reason to why you got the "error" alert. So, make sure to output a valid JSON string - in PHP, you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: @it_is_a_literature regarding first alert from **error** section, you shall set the header in your php file(**header('Content-Type: application/json');**) and use **json_encode** with echo.  And for twice function call you shall **return false** at the end of function ajax().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it looks like your server is not setup correctly, since your `PHP` script is not executed and response simply returns the contents of the script (I see you've already sorted that out with `mod_php`).

Secondly, `{"name", "myname"}` is not a valid `JSON`. Your response should be `{"name": "myname"}` or for convenience you should always `json_encode` a `PHP` array like:

```
<?php
// Set the correct Content-Type
// this helps when viewing in browser console, and is generally needed
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Create an array with needed response data
$result = [
    'name' => 'myname'
];

// Convert PHP array to a correct JSON string and echo it
echo json_encode($result);
```

That way your `JSON`will always be valid or at least you will see errors that will help you debug.

After you've corrected your response, you can do something like:

```
success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // var stringData = JSON.stringify(response); you don't need this
    // since jqXHR object already contains the raw response text

    // It's recommended to prefix variable name with $
    // that way you will always know that it is a JQuery object
    var $mytext = $("#remote");
    $mytext.text(jqXHR.responseText);

    // console.log(response); is better than alert 
    // unless you really need to pause the script
    alert(response.name);
}
```

Please note that `JQuery` is smart enough to see if a request is a `pre-flight` request, so your callbacks should be only triggered when the second request delivers the content.

Answer (score 4):

@it_is_a_literature regarding for first issue (**alert from error section**), you shall set the header in your php file(**header('Content-Type: application/json');**) and use **json_encode with echo**. And for twice function call you shall **return false** at the end of function ajax().

Test.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function Ajax( ) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:855/remote.php';
    $.ajax(url, {
        type:"post",   
        crossDomain: "true",
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSend:function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',"Basic " + btoa("xxxx:xxxx"))},
        success:function(response){
        data = JSON.stringify(response);
            alert(data);
            mytext = $("#remote");
            mytext.append(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
};
</script>

<input type="button" value="show content" onclick="Ajax();">
<p id="remote">the content on remote webpage</p>
```

Response.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo  json_encode(array("name","myname"));
?>
```

Response:

[image: First hit to Resposne.php]

[image: no second function call]

Comment: The "headers" and `json_encode` is already mentioned in my response. Also, your answer makes absolutely no sense. Ho is `return false` helping? The function is not called twice, two requests are needed and are automatically made by JQuery since it is a `CORS` request.